# Как найти совпадение из excel между 2-мя столбцами в Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть 2 столбца, одно со значением ФИО, второе строка с различными данной в которой есть тоже ФИО.
В каждом столбце хаотичный регистр. Надо найти совпадение строк между столбцами и записать в файл.
Пробовал в Pandas, но ругается ...
Подскажите как правильно написать код?

Так ошибка

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('payers.xlsx')
df[df['PAY_'].str.contains("|".join(df['CLIENT']),case=False)]

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 import pandas as pd
2 df = pd.read_excel('payers.xlsx')
----> 3 df[df['PAY_'].str.contains("|".join(df['CLIENT']),case=False)]

TypeError: sequence item 7198: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользутесь `str.contains`. Параметр `case=False` устанавливает нечувствительность к регистру. Поиск идёт по паттерну или регулярному выражению

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Иванов', 'Петров', 'Сидоров'], 'col2': ['текстивановтекст', 'текст', 'иванов']})
df[df['col2'].str.contains("|".join(df['col1']),case=False)]
>>>
    col1    col2
0   Иванов  текстивановтекст
```

Comment: Ошибка ( import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('payers.xlsx')
df[df['PAY_'].str.contains("|".join(df['CLIENT']),case=False)]

Comment: А что у вас в столбцах этих? Какая информация?

Comment: В одном столбце данные платежного поручения в котором есть ФИО, а в другом только ФИО. Я хотел сравнить на булево значение, какие значения совпадают, а какие нет.

Comment: Имею ввиду PAY_ и CLIENT

Comment: текстовые записи, а это заголовки

Comment: Ругается что вместо строки число пришло